# Packaged Electron App cannot find module sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, electron

**Background**

Within an Electron app, sqlite3 doesn't work right after `npm install --save`. I got it working after doing some web research, by:

(1) downgrading my node version (via `n`) to match Electron's node version; and

(2) rebuilding sqlite with the right module name/targets with this `package.json` script:
`"rebuild-sqlite3": "cd node_modules/sqlite3 && npm run prepublish && node-gyp configure --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=../lib/binding/electron-v1.2-darwin-x64 && node-gyp rebuild --target=1.2.6 --arch=x64 --target_platform=darwin --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=../lib/binding/electron-v1.2-darwin-x64"`

After that, Sqlite3 works in development (i.e. when I run `electron .` in the project dir).

**Problem**

I package the app with `electron-packager`: `"./node_modules/.bin/webpack -p && ./node_modules/electron-packager/cli.js ./ --out ./bin --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --version=1.2.6 --overwrite --ignore=\"ignore|bin|node_modules\""`

When I open the app by double-clicking the created (appName).app, the console complains: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module

**Question**

How can I get sqlite3 to be found in the final packaged product? Even "hacks" or workarounds are welcome, as I tried various fixes to no avail.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem and that seems the question that most correctly describes it. This question deserves and answer :)

Comment: This was a while ago. I eventually did get it working, but don't remember the steps. They were similar to the solution posted by Adi here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716594/electron-app-cant-find-sqlite3-module

Answer (score 3):

I leave this answer for someone who has the same problem and is wasting their time to figure out.

**step1**

`npm install sqlite3`

`electron .`

I expected to work fine. but I had an error 'cannot find node module sqlite3'

**step2**

`npm install electron-rebuild --save-dev`

`electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3`

`electron .`

it worked.

but if you used 'electron-packager' to package and make executable file, It didn't work. the same error occured.

```
"electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=new --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Electron Test\"",
```

**step3**

I spent pretty much time to figure out. At the end, I figured out. **the solution was using electron-packager API and integrating afterCopy with electron-rebuild.**

```
# build.js
const packager = require('electron-packager');
const rebuild = require('electron-rebuild');

packager({
    dir: '../dir',
    overwrite: true,
    asar: true,
    platform: 'win32',
    arch: 'ia32',
    icon: 'assets/icons/win/icon.ico',
    prune: true,
    out: 'hello',
    executableName: 'hello',
    afterCopy: [(buildPath, electronVersion, platform, arch, callback) => {
    rebuild.rebuild({ buildPath, electronVersion, arch })
      .then(() => callback())
      .catch((error) => callback(error));
  }],
})
```

`node build.js`

reference

- [electron-rebuild manual 'How can I integrate this into Electron packager?'](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild)
- [electron-packager API doc](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the `--ignore=\"ignore|bin|node_modules\"` you pass to `electron-packager` ignore everything in the `node_modules` dir, the very place where the `sqlite3` module is installed?

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out first. The packaging command I used was taken from a web example; I might've made some incorrect assumptions about it.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, but I haven't included anything at ignores node_modules. Did you find a solution?