# Electron app cant find sqlite3 module

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm, electron

In my electron app I have installed sqlite3 via npm

```
npm install sqlite3
```

But once i try to interact with the database it cant find the database, here is the log:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'D:\play\electron-quick-start\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v1.3-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'

Here is JS code:

```
console.log('whooooo');

var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('../db/info.db');

db.serialize(function () {
    db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");   

    var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
    }
    stmt.finalize();

    db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function (err, row) {
        console.log(row.id + ": " + row.info);
    });
});
db.close();
```

I also try in this way:

```
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source
```

but it fails to install!

Also, i am using Python3. How do you install a module to work with electron?

Comment: You got any solution for this?

Answer (score 38):

Firstly:

`npm install electron-rebuild`

then try this several times:

`./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -w sqlite3 -p`

Comment: works perfectly, if on windows use some bash client (I used git bash)

Comment: second step failed, tips me 'node-gyp' have a wrong proxy, but I don't know how to change the node-gyp's proxy setting

Comment: This worked for issue I was having with better-sqlite3  ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -w better-sqlite3 -p  :) but did not work for sqlite3 :( ... I was trying out both modules and had issues getting both to work, so this at least allowed me to move forward using one of them. Thxs

Comment: this did it on macos catalina for me

Answer (score 9):

You have to build this native module with Electron based configurations.

Try:
1. `cd node_modules/sqlite3`
2. `npm run prepublish`
3. `node-gyp configure --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=../lib/binding/electron-v1.3-win32-x64`
4. `node-gyp rebuild --target=1.3.1 --arch=x64 --target_platform=win32 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=../lib/binding/electron-v1.3-win32-x64`

This is assuming you have the very latest version of electron. You can change the config to match your electron version.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks, remember if you don't have node gyp, install it before do this things..

Comment: It's not working for me. Any solution for this error? Error is : Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'path_to_project\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v1.4-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41307807/i-am-getting-an-error-while-connecting-to-sqlite3-database is there any solution for this one

Comment: I ended up with the error `npm ERR! missing script: prepublish`

Comment: Fails at step #2 - `Missing script: "prepublish"`

Answer (score 8):

If none of these are working try this.

```
npm install electron-builder
```

Add this in your script tag of package.json file

```
 "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
```

Then execute this

```
npm run postinstall
```

This saved a lot of my time

Comment: Didn't work. I get the same error. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3):

1: Include rebuild in Package.json file and install npm electron-rebuild

```
{
  "name": "electron-quick-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "quick",
    "start",
    "tutorial",
    "demo"
  ],
  "author": "author",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "electron": "1.7",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.13"
  }
}
```

2: install python 2.7 and add its path to environmental variable e.g C:\Python27;

3: npm INSTALL and then 
   npm run rebuild

Comment: +1 for ("rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3"), it's solved the problem for me after running the command "npm run rebuild" in terminal

Answer (score 2):

You have just installed the `sqlite3` module but you need to rebuild it to run on a specific platform. You'll need `electron-rebuild` package to rebuild the binary.

Run Command `npm i --save-dev electron-rebuild` from your project directory.After Installing the ˚`electron-rebuild`. Run the following command to build sqlite3 binary for your platform.

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -w sqlite3 -p
```

If rebuild fails, run `npm install` and then run the above-given command once again.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. It tells me 

 '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: go to /node_modules/.bin/ and open terminal there. run command "electron-rebuild -w sqlite3 -p"

Comment: Well it originally failed cuz I didn't have python 2.7, after I installed 2.7 I got this error https://pastebin.com/xmhsG85A

Comment: You have to install windows build tools, vc++ and python before start building the sqlite3 module. Download and install VC++ 2015.3 v140 toolset (x86,x64)

Comment: Took a while to download the build tools, but afterwards, I re-ran the cmd and it worked :D already tested some of SQLite's features and everything seems to be working. TYSM! I just about gave up trying to use SQLite in electron cause nothing else worked!

Comment: if you are using sqlite3 with electron, i suggest you to use http://knexjs.org/ Knex Module. I buit 3 application on top of it and it's too easy to maintain database with it.

Answer (score 0):

For cross compilation try `sqlite3-offline` or `sqlite3-offline-next` packages wich are working out of the box

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as; I tested many things on this page.  this worked.

```
npm add sqlite3
```