# I am getting an error while connecting to sqlite3 database

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

I am getting an error while connecting to `sqlite3` database.

This is my code

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('testdb');

db.serialize(function(){

    dbb.run("create table user (id int, db text)");
    var stmt = db.prepare("insert into user values(?,?)");
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){

        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.toLocateTimeString();
        stmt.run(i,n);

    }   
    stmt.finalize();

    db.each("select id, dt from user",function(err,row){
        console.log("user id:"+row.id,row.dt);
    });
});
db.close();
```

Error is:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'path_to_project\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v1.4-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node'

When i check in this folder `node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding`, it's having a folder and a file like `node-v48-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node` instead of `electron-v1.4-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node`.

Somebody suggested me to change the folder name `node-v48-win32-ia32` to `electron-v1.4-win32-ia32`. Then it will work. But it returns another error

> ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173 Uncaught Error: The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.
>   \?\path_to_project\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v1.4-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node

Can anyone suggest a solution for this? I searched a lot, but no solution found for this one.

Comment: Nobody experienced such an issue before?

Comment: any nodejs/electron experts, please help me..

Comment: i tried this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716594/electron-app-cant-find-sqlite3-module. But it's not working

Comment: even this too. https://gist.github.com/maximilian-ruppert/9de273f72c1ba4aa62d6. But not working

Answer (score 3):

I got this working by using electron-rebuild

First install:

`npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
npm install --save-dev electron-prebuilt`

Then, in your `package.json` add the script:

`"rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3 -v 1.X"`

and run

`npm run rebuild`

I had to run it several times, changing the `-v` to the version needed, 1.2, 1.4 or 1.6

Comment: Thanks, I got the same problem and the above solution worked for me.

Comment: I am using version 1.7.

Comment: I followed your instructions but still I am getting error.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Victor Ivens said above,

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
```

Then, in your package.json add the script:

```
"rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3 -v 1.7" // for version 1.7
```

and voila, it works.
You can ignore prebuilt