# Electron i32 app cant find sqlite3 module

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have Electron App with [electron-sqlite3 dependency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-sqlite3) when I'm exporting it to exe using `electron-packager`
the x64  version working fine.

```
electron-packager .  app64  --platform=win32 --arch=x64
electron-packager .  app32  --platform=win32 --arch=ia32
```

but the i32 version throw this error message when running the app.

```
 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 
'C:\myApp\myapp-win32-ia32\resources\app\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v4.0-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node'
```

I already tried the suggested solution .[in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716594/electron-app-cant-find-sqlite3-module) and other thread

in one of the threads found this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41207052/2090426)  talking about using native node modue is the issue.

How can I fix my app to run on both x64 and x32

---

After more digging I think it is npm related issue because node_modules directory only has x64 version of the module since my current os is 64
and this Dir is empty

```
node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v4.0-win32-ia32
```